# Derivative/relative of "introspection" but for external phenomena

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a derivative of the word *introspection* that does not relate to "spect"-ing oneself but external phenomena yet still contains the *spection* part?  Like for example *extraspection* (which, I guess, is not a word).  For example:

> It took a lot of *extraspection* to arrive to the scientific findings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are trying to say here. Is that the actual phrase where you want to use the word? Anyway, one word that means pretty much what you seem to want and that does derive from the same root is [*inspection*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inspect):

> tr.v. in·spect·ed, in·spect·ing, in·spects
>   1. To examine carefully and critically, especially for flaws.
>   2. To review or examine officially: The commander inspected the troops.

I suspect, however, that you are needlessly tying yourself to the whole *spection* thing and that a better word would be one of *analysis*, *investigation*, *research* etc.

Answer (score 0):

***Meditation*** can be outward, as well. It commonly *implies* inward looking because everyone has to start there.